Why is Claude 3.5 Sonnet so good?
I was curious if it is known what about the design and training of Claude made it so good. I find it very impressive to use and how well it does on benchmarks compared to say GPT-4o. I am surprised that OpenAI has not yet released a model that outperforms it. Does Anthropic have comparable computing resources to OpenAI? Is there something about their design that is more effective than the design of ChatGPT's models?

gpt4o clearly beats Sonnet on human evals, e.g. https://huggingface.co/spaces/lmsys/chatbot-arena-leaderboard:


The “Arena score” are very close for the different tools, so they have similar performances?

This answer would be better if it explained the relevant data from the leaderboard. A link and an image without comment is not that helpful.
